# Report on contacts, tasks and Notes

Tags: custom-report-type, custom-reports

I am trying to create a report on 3 objects

1. Contact
2. task
3. Content note

but there is no standard report type to create a report on these 3 objects altogether, I have tried creating custom report type but I am not getting task and content note object, can anyone please suggest if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

To create reports outside of standard reports we need to create custom report types. Custom report types can include up to 4 objects in a parent-child mode, include fields from lookups to other objects as well as a whole bunch of other features.

Custom report types needed when you have a requirement to report on more objects than standard reports allow. You can add up to 4 layers of objects as long as they have a parent-child relationship.

All objects are all related with lookups and each successive object needs to be a child or grandchild of the master object.

> ContentNote, task and contact do not have the parent-child
> relationship. So it is not possible.

Anyhow, you can create **Activities with [OBJECT] Report Type** for relating Contact and task. For more Information refer [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002591&type=1).

But contentNote do not directly share the parent-child relationship in salesforce with Contact or activities.